# Is my proof for Surjective functions correct?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The definition was: $f: A\rightarrow B$ is surjective if and only if $\forall C\subseteq B, f^{-1}(C)\not=\emptyset$

My proof:

Showing the forward direction we are given $f$ is surjective implying $C\not=\emptyset$. Then $\exists c\in C$ and $\exists a\in A$ such that $f(a)=c\in C$, by definition of surjectivity. Now, by definition of inverse images it is implied that $a\in f^{-1}(C)$, hence $f^{-1}(C)\not=\emptyset$. Now showing the backwards direction we assume $f^{-1}(C)\not=\emptyset$ with the assumption that $C$ is nonempty. Suppose there is a $b\in B$ then $b\in \{b\}$ which implies $\{b\}\subseteq B$. Since $f^{-1}(C)$ is nonempty we have an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\in \{b\}$, but this implies there is a $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. So for each element in the codomain $B$, there exists an element in $A$ that can be mapped back to the element in $B$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

I am 95% confident my proof is correct, but since this is a proof-'writing' class I wanted to get feedback on how I can improve wording, syntax, and anything else I might not be considering.

Comment: $C\neq\emptyset$ should be given, not implied. $f$ is surjective doesn't imply $C\neq\emptyset$. Your proof is correct but can be made a lot more concise: $$\\$$$f$ is surjective iff $\forall b\in B\exists a\in A\mid f(a)=b$ iff $\forall b\in B\exists a\in A\mid a\in f^{-1}(\{b\})$ iff $\forall C(\neq\emptyset)\subseteq B\exists D(\neq\emptyset)\subseteq A\mid D\subseteq f^{-1}(C)$ iff $\forall C(\neq\emptyset)\subseteq B, f^{-1}(C)\neq\emptyset$

Comment: I think the best way to improve is, to get the confidence to stick with what you have written, because this builds some 'mathematical confidence', or better go over your proof and try to spot some flaws and how to fix them. In my opinion your proof is fine (not perfect), and has some minor flaws. So your proof is maybe a 95% of 100%. You can be proud of that, and the rest will come with the time. To name a few things: How does $f$ surjective imply that $C\neq\emptyset$ and what is $C$ in the firstplace? Also when writing a proof, maybe you want to leave quantors out, and write 'exists'

Comment: instead of '$\exists$'. In the proof of "$\Leftarrow$", you might want to ommit the second "there is $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$", as this adds nothing new. Also in the proof of this implication, you maybe want to start with "let $b\in B$ be arbitrary". It reads as you pick one specific $b$, which then does not fit to your conclusion "So for each element in $B$ ... ". But as I said. These are minor mistakes. Maybe typos. Maybe my(!) lack of the english language.

Comment: @Trap.Lord One general rule of syntax is to never use hybrids between natural language and formal language, such as when writing $\exists c \in C$. This should either be expressed as *there exists $c \in C$* or $(\exists c)(c \in C)$.

Comment: Thank you all! I will digest this information and come post an edited version, once I feel confident.

Comment: @Cornman Sorry to tag you but it seemed like you were invested in helping me improve my proof writing skills I was wondering if you can take a look at my new proof and consider my question after it, or should I just post a new question entirely?

Comment: @Trap.Lord You can post your proof as an answer below. Answering your own question is always a good idea. Also you could edit your other question, but I would recommand posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited Proof:

Showing the forward direction we are given $f$ is surjective and $C\not=\emptyset$. Then let $c\in C$ be arbritary then there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=c\in C$, by definition of surjectivity. Now, by definition of inverse images it is implied that $a\in f^{-1}(C)$, hence $f^{-1}(C)\not=\emptyset$. Now showing the backwards direction we assume $f^{-1}(C)\not=\emptyset$ with the assumption that $C$ is nonempty. Suppose there is a $b\in B$ then $b\in \{b\}$ which implies $\{b\}\subseteq B$. Since $f^{-1}(C)$ is nonempty we have an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\in \{b\}$. So for each element in the codomain $B$, there exists an element in $A$ that can be mapped back to the element in $B$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

But now my issue is my conclusion feels wonky because I have been talking about the subsets but in my conclusion I am referring to the elements. Is that alright or is there a more concise way to finish it off with how I have written the proof.

Comment: In the proof of $\Rightarrow$ you somehow write $B$ when you mean $C$. Also you might want to ommit (in red) the $f(a)=c\color{red}{c\in C}$ as we already know that $c\in C$. Also a definition does not really "imply" something. It is just reciting the definiton. As $b\in\{b\}$ does not imply $\{b\}\subseteq B$ either. You write shorter $b\in\{b\}\subseteq B$. You should swap the $C$ with $\{b\}$ in "Since $f^{-1}(C)$ is nonempty". Note that your assumption is that the preimage of EVERY subset of $C$ is nonempty, and therefore $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is nonempty.

Comment: Your conclusion at the end is correct. You have shown the surjectivity of $f$, as you have shown for every $b\in B$ there is an $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$.

Comment: But as I said before. Do not overthink it. You do not have to write perfect proofs from the beginning on, and proof righting depends on style too. Just try to find your own style. Try to figure out what your lecturer or tutor wants and so on.

Comment: @Cornman You are an awesome individual, thank you for helping me on my journey to becoming a better mathematician.

Comment: You are welcome.